# Extension to support Inline image preview?

Tags: visual-studio

Would like to ask if someone knows of any extension for `Visual Studio` version2019/2022 capable of displaying an **inline** image preview upon ***hovering*** a picture file.

Similar to this [extension](https://github.com/kisstkondoros/gutter-preview) for ***vscode***:

[image]

While searching I have found some, but these you usually need to click on some kind of button or window to create the image, instead of displaying it under the mouse.

Answer (score 2):

The new [Image Preview extension by Mad Kristensen](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.ImagePreview) can do that.